# Polymer/platform.js breaks jQuery on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, polymer

I seem to have reached a showstopping bug with Polymer in my current project, and none of the solutions I've found have worked.

Essentially, whenever I load platform.js alongside jQuery, I get the following error every time I click anywhere on the page:

```
TypeError: elem.getAttribute is not a function


elem.getAttribute( name ) :  
jquery-2.1.1.js (line 1430)
```

Now, this doesn't actually prevent any of my code from running, but it freezes the page for about half a second, which is obviously unaccaptable since it's triggered by every click event. I can't have my UI take half a second to respond to click/touch events.

I'm aware that there is already a question addressing this issue on SO, but I've already wrapped the one occurrence of `document` in my code as per the accepted solution, and nothing has changed.

I've already decided to stay the hell away from Polymer for the foreseeable future because of various bugs like this and lack of polish in general, but I can't just drop it now because I'm already using a lot of custom Polymer elements. Can somebody please help me get this resolved?

Comment: Are you loading platform.js before you load jquery? What version of platform.js are you using? What version of jquery? Can you come up with a minimal set of code to reproduce this issue?